# Quotient of Cohen forcing

Tags: logic, set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

How do we know that the quotient of the Boolean algebra associated with Cohen forcing by a generic filter is either atomic or isomorphic to the Cohen forcing?
I know that Cohen forcing is the unique separable atomless complete Boolean algebra, but then why is the quotient either atomic or atomless?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A quotient (homomorphic image) of Cohen algebra may not be atomless or purely atomic. Although you can find a maximal antichain A in a quotient B such that each a in A is an atom or B restricted to a is atomless - this is true of every separable algebra and quotients are clearly separable.

Comment: This answer seems contradictory with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1337273/cohen-forcing-factoring?rq=1 Did I miss something?

Comment: I think I got it. Suppose $[a]$ is an atom, let $[y] \ne 0$. We have $a \land y \le a$ hence $[a \land y]=0$ or $[a \land y]=[a]$. In the second case, $b=[a \land y ]$ is an atom and $b \le [y]$. In the first case $-a \lor -y \in F$. As $F$ is generic, $-a \in F$ or $-y \in F$. But $[a] \ne 0$ so $-y \in F$ which means $[y]=0$ contradiction.